# pandas: how to create dataframe from dict of lists

Tags: json, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

How do I convert this into a pandas dataframe?

```
df_components = { "result1": 
  {"data" : [["43", "48", "27", "12"], ["67", "44", "24", "11"], ["11.85", "6.31", "5.18", "11.70"]],
  "index" : [["Device_use_totala11. PS4", "Unweighted base"], ["Device_use_totala11. PS4", "Base"], ["Device_use_totala11. PS4", "Mean"]],
  "columns" : [["Age", "Under 30"], ["Age", "30-44"], ["Age", "45-54"], ["Age", "55+"]]}
}
```

It's a dict with list of lists.

I thought this would work but it returns something funky which doesnt look like a dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(df_components['result1'])
```

Output looks like:

```
columns  [[Age, Under 30], [Age, 30-44], [Age, 45-54], ...
data     [[43, 48, 27, 12], [67, 44, 24, 11], [11.85, 6...
index    [[Device_use_totala11. PS4, Unweighted base], ...
```

Expected output:

a multi index df, something similar to the table below?

[image]

Comment: Note that I can't reproduce your output, I have a `ValueError: arrays must all be same length` when doing `pd.DataFrame(df_components)` with pandas 0.15.1 or 0.17.1

Comment: df_components shouldve been df_components['result1']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dict is not formatted properly to transform it directly into a DataFrame, you need to do:

```
d = df_components["result1"]
df = pd.DataFrame(d["data"],
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d["columns"]),
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d["index"]))

df
                                              Age                   
                                         Under 30 30-44 45-54    55+
Device_use_totala11. PS4 Unweighted base       43    48    27     12
                         Base                  67    44    24     11
                         Mean               11.85  6.31  5.18  11.70
```

Comment: I think it may because the columns are multiindex and the index are not?

Comment: ah ok, `Age` and `Device...` are higher index ? The thing is that the key of your dict must be either columns or index, and in tuple if multiple index. You only pass the name of the column or index (the one absent in the dict) afterward.

Comment: How about now? Ive added the name of the df to the dict. And Yes, Age and Device are the higher (outter) index.

Comment: But what do you want as output ?

Comment: a multiindex dataframe